# .NET WPF canvas drawing high CPU usage

Tags: c#, wpf, canvas

I have a problem with canvas in .NET WPF.

I have following code to run drawing in new thread:

```
    public void RenderWPFMiniMap()
    {

        while (true)
        {
            bool focused = false;
            Thread.Sleep(1000/60);
            try
            {
                this.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
                {
                    focused = MinimapTab.IsSelected;
                });

                if (Api._user.userData.Ready && focused)
                {
                    base.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(Draw));
                }
                else
                {
                    Thread.Sleep(1000);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex);
            }

        }
    }


    private void DrawElipse(bool fill, Color color, double x, double y, Size size)
    {
        Ellipse el = new Ellipse();
        if (fill)
        {
            el.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(color);
        }
        else
        {
            el.Stroke = new SolidColorBrush(color);
        }
        el.Width = size.Width;
        el.Height = size.Height;
        el.Margin = new Thickness(x, y, 0, 0);
        canvas.Children.Add(el);
    }
```

base.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(Draw)); runs few methods to render objects from collections (adding to canvas is like DrawElipse() method)

Which means I'm just adding objects to canvas.

But it takes unreasonable high CPU resources to draw. (60FPS - 10-12%CPU)
(+ I need to render whole Canvas not just around the player)

Comment: Why are you using a Thread, instead of the [CompositionTarget.Rendering](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.compositiontarget.rendering?view=windowsdesktop-6.0) event or a [DispatcherTimer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.threading.dispatchertimer?view=windowsdesktop-6.0) or an animation?

Comment: Well, you are hitting the UI thread at least every 16 ms.  That can definitely cause high CPU.

Comment: @RobGoodwin I tried render it every 100ms(10 FPS) but it was almost the same. And I need to render it for atleast 20-30 FPS

Comment: But what do you want to achieve? An animation? Possibly you're using wrong WPF tools for your task.

Comment: This looks like a piece of very inefficient code which leads to the conclusion that you are very likely tackling your problem the wrong way. If you would share more details describing the original problem you are trying to solve, I'm sure you will receive help.